# Video Twilio - Setting up a Ringtone for videocalls

Tags: twilio

We're using Twilio Programmable Video and we'd like to set up:
- A ringtone while a participant is waiting in the room.
- A "ringing" to notify the other side that a participant is waiting in the room.

All in all, a performance like a voice call.

We have checked API Reference, AudioTrack and Media section, without success.  (https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta4/docs/)

Any idea to configure this performance?

Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no functionality in the Twilio API for providing a ring tone, however you could implement it yourself.

You would need to send an invite to the participant that hasn't entered the room yet. You could do that with a server sent event or websocket. Then you would play the ringtone (using an `<audio>` element or the web audio API) until the user entered the room themself, at which point you would stop playback of the ringtone.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: i am looking for the exact same functionality as the original question. You are suggesting, that it can only be implemented on the front end? I am planning to play the ringtone on a mobile device, where we could have many interruptions in our app (like backgrounding, or muting the device), what makes the experience quite crap.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are worried about the notification to the other user that they have a call waiting? If you are building with the Web, then you have the options that I described above as well as push notifications on platforms that support them. Your profile suggests that you are an iOS developer though, in which case you can take advantage of CallKit to provide full VOIP notification to the other user. [Check out the example application here for more detail](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift).

Comment: The notifications are fine. I understand the option of using CallKit, however i have decided against it, because i do not want the call to be present in the users call history. I have read, that in conference calls there is an option to specify 'waitURL', and i am looking for something similar with peer to peer video calls.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for wait music for the person that has already called into the room? So, the thing is, a room in this case is just an abstraction, until there are two people there, there is no connection. Since it's peer to peer, if there's only one peer then there is no connection, nothing else to play music down, there is no "conference room" as in telephony. This is why I suggest playing wait music from the device itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However it would be awesome to play some sound "from the room", could you point me to a direction where i could submit it as a feature request ;)

Comment: Your welcome to send this into [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) but like I said, the "room" is just a concept and when there's only one person there's nothing to send the music "from".